# Web Scraping – Filling in Forms -Runtime Error -"1004"

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**I have used SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0.exe and Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69**

I'm trying to scrape "**Name**" data from this website "**http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/**", 
I chose a Member State from the dropdown, so '**GB-United Kingdom**' in this instance.
Then enter the VAT Number(Let's say - "`238554836`", and click on **Verify**.

The issue i'm getting in my code is the

> "runtime error 1004 : Method range of object - 'Global' failed"

in the 4th line of the Code(`While` Statement)

```
Sub formfill()

Dim Driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim count As Long
Sheets("DATA").Activate

Set Driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
count = 1

While (Len(Range("A" & Count)) > 0)

Driver.Get "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/"
Driver.FindElementById("countryCombobox").SendKeys "GB"
Driver.FindElementById("number").SendKeys Range("A" & Count)
Driver.FindElementById("submit").Click

Range("B" & Count)Driver.FindElementByXPath("//table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]").Text
count = count + 1

Wend
Driver.Quit
End Sub
```

Here is the image for your reference.[image: Error Image]

To Summarize :-

**I have a list of VAT number list in a excel sheet, the code will take the number from excel file and paste it in the "VAT no" field and click on VERIFY, and scrape the Name of the company.**

Comment: If you have the Selenium library added to your project references you shouldn't need to use `CreateObject` and since you've declared the variable as `new Selenium.ChromeDriver` the instance is already created so the line below is redundant anyway.

Comment: I have edited the code @NickSlash. Please have a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized count with an explicit value so it's start value will be 0. There is no range A0 hence your error. You also need to alter count (presumably decrement towards 0) in your loop so as to satisfy your exit condition.

Comment: Please have a look into the code.
In my other system i get this "Runtime Error -2146232576 - 
Atomation Error

Comment: Though i have performed all the tasks of installing Selenium , also installed the Chrome Driver too, then the references too in the VBA editor.
But other system just cant go past Automation Error.